# Loading properties from a class into another class

Tags: java, properties

I'm trying to load properties into some scripts. It works when I do it like so:

```
public class MyClass {

    public static void myMethod() {
        Properties prop = new Properties();

        InputStream config = Properties.class.getResourceAsStream("/config/config");
        try {
            prop.load(config);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("placeholder"));
```

This will successfully print out the value "placeholder" in the console from the `/config/config` text file.

I'd like to make this a little easier and implement a data grabbing class, implementing a `switch` block to differentiate between different properties files. It's seen as below:

```
public class Data {

    public static Properties getProperties(String file) {
        Properties prop = new Properties();

        switch (file) {
            case "config":
                InputStream config = Properties.class.getResourceAsStream("/config/config");
                try {
                    prop.load(config);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        case "objectlocations":
                InputStream objectlocations = Properties.class.getResourceAsStream("/properties/objectlocations");
                try {
                    prop.load(objectlocations);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }
        return prop;
    }
}
```

With this class, depending on what properties I need, I can call the file I wish to call.

It all checks out until I try to put it back into `MyClass.myMethod`:

```
public class MyClass {

    public static void myMethod() {
        Properties prop = new Properties();

        Data.getProperties("config");
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("placeholder"));
```

Implementing it like this prints out "null" in the console, telling me that the properties never got loaded from `Data.getProperties("config");`.

What do I need to add, move around, or remove to successfully load properties using a `getProperties` method? Is it a problem with my switch, and if so should I just make different methods for each file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change the line to `prop = Data.getProperties("config");`  Data.getProperties returns a Properties type that goes nowhere. You can do `Properties prop = Data.getProperties("config")` as well.

Comment: @SaviourSelf Works great, thank you very much. You can throw the answer up if you'd like.

Comment: You should seriously consider making the argument type an `enum` instead of a String.  As long as it's a String, calling code has to “just know” which string arguments are valid and which are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the following lines:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
Data.getProperties("config");
```

The Data.getProperties line returns a Properties type which holds the information you're looking for. You need to assign that object to your local Properties object.

If you change the above lines to `Properties prop = Data.getProperties("config");`, you'll get the object you're looking for.